# Left and right aligned text boxes

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am writing a thesis and at the bottom of the title page, I need to include two participating institutes. So far, I have come up with this (using `\parbox`, but I cannot figure out how to right align the second block because `\begin{flushright}` starts a new paragraph and thus adds another line:

```
\parbox[t][3cm][t]{7cm}{\normalsize Figurative Unit (Optional)\\
Department of Blabla\\
University of Blabla} 
\parbox[t][3cm][t]{7cm}{\normalsize Chair of Mickey Mouse Science\\
Institute of Disneyland Studies\\
FSF Blabla}
```

This results in:

[image]

As I said, I would like the right text block to be right-aligned to the margin of the page, which is set to 40mm  ( `\newgeometry{left=40mm,right=40mm,top=30mm}` ). In the above example I used absolute distance measures but I assume it could be done more elegantly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Using `\hfill` instead of the space (in your code the end-of-line) between the first and second `\parbox` should do.

Comment: No, that doesn't do. Or maybe I didn't understand what you meant, exactly. Maybe you could provide this as an answer?

Comment: It's better if you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: No. There's nothing more to explain, really. And I think this is a problem that has been solved thousands of times already (although Google hasn't much to offer.

Comment: Try `\normalsize\raggedleft` in the second parbox. If that doesn't do what you want, add a MWE.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. You can add this as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use two minipages, like this.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
Figurative Unit (Optional)\\
Department of Blabla\\
University of Blabla
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
Chair of Mickey Mouse Science\\
Institute of Disneyland Studies\\
FSF Blabla
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Even better and more elegant ;-)

Comment: +1. Note that one still may use `\raggedleft` instead of the `flushright` environment inside the minipage.

Comment: Thanks @PeterJansson! I've benefited from all the information on this site as a long-time lurker, so I thought I'd see if I could contribute anything.

Answer (score 8):

Try `\normalsize\raggedleft` in the second parbox.